# Routing error when testing API made with Blueprint in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm having troubles when testing an API made with Flask-Restplus, integrating it into an existing application.

The structure (not complete, the relevant pieces) of the project is as follows (root folder is called portal)

```
|
|-api -> Blueprint directory package
|   |
|   |-> endpoints -> package for endpoints
|   |        |-> __init__.py -> Empty
|   |        |-> token.py -> The token endpoint
|   |-> __init__.py -> empty
|   |-> business.py -> logic to create tokens
|   |-> restplus.py -> API initialization
|   |-> serializer.py -> token serializer
|-tests -> Tests folder
|   |-> helpers.py -> Base classes for testing, setup, etc
|   |-> tests_api.py -> API tests
|-> app.py -> app initialization and config 
|-> main.py -> Entry point
```

**main.py**

```
import sys

from flask import Blueprint

from portal.app import app
from portal import libs

from portal.api.restplus import api
from portal.api.endpoints.token import ns as tokens_namespace


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port = 5000

    host = app.config.get('HOST', '127.0.0.1')

    # Configure the Blueprint for API
    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(tokens_namespace)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    # For Dev environment we set the app root path to the current working directory
    import os
    app.root_path = os.getcwd()
    print "Running in", app.root_path, " with DEBUG=", app.config.get('DEBUG', False)
    app.run(host,
            port,
            app.config.get('DEBUG', False),
            use_reloader=True
    )
```

**app.py**

```
import sys
import os
import datetime
import logging
from logging import Formatter
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, abort, request

from utils.mail import CustomMail as Mail


app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "crackthis"
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')

if os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'local_settings.py')):
    app.config.from_pyfile('local_settings.py')


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://%s@%s/%s' % (
    app.config['DB_USER'], app.config['DB_HOST'], app.config['DB_NAME'])

def in_test():
    return "".join(sys.argv).find('nosetests') >= 0

Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('portal', 'templates')).globals['url_for'] = url_for

mail = Mail(app)

from filters import CUSTOM_FILTERS
app.jinja_env.filters.update(CUSTOM_FILTERS)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip, now=datetime.datetime.now())


# Initialize event handling
from blinker import Namespace
signals = Namespace()
from portal.events import handlers

def log_exception(exc_info, app_ctx):
    app.logger.exception(
        """
        Request:   {method} {path}
        IP:        {ip}
        Agent:     {agent_platform} | {agent_browser} {agent_browser_version}
        Raw Agent: {agent}
        user:      {user}
        """.format(
            method=request.method,
            path=request.path,
            ip=request.remote_addr,
            agent_platform=request.user_agent.platform,
            agent_browser=request.user_agent.browser,
            agent_browser_version=request.user_agent.version,
            agent=request.user_agent.string,
            user=app_ctx.logged_in
        )
    )


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error_page(error):
    from portal.utils.app_ctx import AppContext
    app_ctx = AppContext('connect', 'error')
    log_exception(error, app_ctx)
    return render_template("errors/server_error_new.html", app_ctx=app_ctx), 500

@app.errorhandler(404)
def server_page_not_found(error):
    from portal.utils.app_ctx import AppContext
    app_ctx = AppContext('connect', 'error')
    log_exception(error, app_ctx)
    return render_template("errors/page_not_found_new.html", app_ctx=app_ctx), 404
```

Now for the Blueprint part

**token.py**

```
from flask import request
from flask_restplus import Resource
from portal.api.business import create_token, update_token, delete_token
from portal.api.serializers import token
from portal.api.restplus import api
from portal.utils.api_helpers import api_authenticate, is_administrator, is_assistant
from portal.models.api import ApiToken


ns = api.namespace('tokens', description='Operations related to deal with tokens')


@ns.route('/')
class TokenCollection(Resource):

    parser = api.parser()
    parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Member username', location='form')
    parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Member password', location='form')

    @api.response(201, 'Token successfully created.')
    @api.response(404, 'Not user with provided credentials')
    @api.response(403, 'Provided password or username are invalid')
    @api.expect(parser)
    def post(self):
        """
        Creates a new token.
        """
        data = request.form
        response, code = create_token(data)
        return response, code


@ns.route('/<string:id>')
@api.response(404, 'Token not found.')
class TokenItem(Resource):

    method_decorators = [is_administrator, api_authenticate]

    @api.marshal_with(token, code=200)
    @api.header('Auth-Token', 'Required field for accessing most API endpoints', required=True)
    def get(self, id):
        """
        Returns a Token.
        """
        token = ApiToken.query.filter(ApiToken.id == id).one()
        return token


    @api.response(204, 'Token successfully deleted.')
    @api.header('Auth-Token', 'Required field for accessing most API endpoints', required=True)
    def delete(self, id):
        """
        Deletes a Token.
        """
        delete_token(id)
        return None, 204
```

**business.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

from portal.db import DB
from portal.models import Program, Member
from portal.models.api import ApiToken

def create_token(data):
    """
    Creates a token to be used in furhter API calls
    :param data: A Dict containing username and password
    :return:
    """
    member = Member()
    member.from_dict(data)

    password = member.password
    username = member.email

    try:
        member = Member.objects.get(username__iexact=username, skip_auth=True)
    except Member.DoesNotExist:
        result = {'error': 'Not user with provided credentials'}
        code = 404
        return result, code

    if not member.check_password(password):
        result = {'error': 'Provided password or username are invalid'}
        code = 403
        return result, code

    try:
        token = ApiToken.objects.get(member=member)
    except ApiToken.DoesNotExist:
        token = ApiToken(member=member)
        token.save()

    code = 201
    return {'id': token.id,
        'token': token.token,
        'member_id': member.id,
        'date': str(token.date)}, code


def update_token(token_id, data):
    """
    Updates date and deleted flag of specified token
    :param token_id: The token id
    :param data: The dict with data
    :return: The Token modifed
    """
    try:
        token = ApiToken.objects.get(id=token_id)
        token.date = datetime.utcnow
        token.is_deleted = data['is_deleted']
        token.save()
    except ApiToken.DoesNotExist:
        result = {'error': 'Could not find Auth Token with provided ID'}
        code = 404
        return result, code

    code = 204
    return {'id': token.id,
        'token': token.token,
        'member_id': token.member_id,
        'date': str(token.date)}, code


def delete_token(token_id):
    """
    Deletes specified token if it exists
    :param token_id: The token ID
    :return:
    """
    try:
        ApiToken.objects.delete(id=token_id)
    except ApiToken.DoesNotExist:
        result = {'error': 'Could not find Auth Token with provided ID'}
        code = 404
        return result, code

    code = 204
    return 'Token deleted successfully', code
```

**restplus.py**

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

api = Api(version='1.0', title='Wizbots API',
          description='Wizbots site Restful API')

@api.errorhandler
def default_error_handler(e):
    message = 'An unhandled exception occurred.'
    return {'message': message}, 500

@api.errorhandler(NoResultFound)
def database_not_found_error_handler(e):
    return {'message': 'A database result was required but none was found.'}, 404
```

**serializers.py**

```
from flask_restplus import fields
from portal.api.restplus import api

token = api.model('ApiToken', {
'id': fields.String(readOnly=True, description='The unique identifier of a Token'),
'token': fields.String(required=True, description='The token value'),
'member_id': fields.String(required=True, description='The Member ID associated with token'),
'date': fields.DateTime(required=True, description='Token creation time'),
})
```

And now the test itself:

**tests_api.py**

```
"""
Test API endpoints
"""
import unittest

from portal.tests import helpers
from portal.app import app
from portal.views import (
views, account, admin, enrollment,
programs, lab, public)


class ApiTests(helpers.ViewBase):

    ############################
    #### setup and teardown ####
    ############################

    def setUp(self):
        super(ApiTests, self).setUp()
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        self.assertEquals(app.debug, False)

    # executed after to each test
    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    ########################
    #### helper methods ####
    ########################

    ###############
    #### tests ####
    ###############
    def test_can_obtain_token(self):
        # Make a call to api endpoint to create a token
        form_data = dict()
        form_data['email'] = 'admin@wizbots.test.com'
        form_data['password'] = 'password'
        response = self.client.post('/api/tokens', data=form_data)
        # Make sure response is ok and contains and Auth-token
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('token', response.data)

    def test_wrong_credentials_token(self):
        pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

When running tests with nosetests:

```
nosetests -s tests/test_api.py:ApiTests.test_can_obtain_token
```

I keep on getting 404:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_obtain_token (portal.tests.test_api.ApiTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/internetmosquito/git/wizbots/portal/src/portal/tests/test_api.py", line 42, in test_can_obtain_token
    form_data = dict()
AssertionError: 404 != 200
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
portal.app: ERROR: 
Request:   POST /api/tokens
IP:        None
Agent:     None | None None
Raw Agent: 
user:      <portal.models.member.AnonymousMember instance at 0x7f73b4654560>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/internetmosquito/python_envs/wizbots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/internetmosquito/python_envs/wizbots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1617, in dispatch_request
self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/home/internetmosquito/python_envs/wizbots/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1600, in raise_routing_exception
raise request.routing_exception
NotFound: 404: Not Found
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.967s
```

It just looks as if the /api/tokens endpoint is unreachable...needless to say this works fine if I fire up the server and use the endpoint either with curl or swaggerUI...any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mcve]? That's a lot of setup needed to recreate.

Comment: That's already cut to the minimun, as I said this is part of a much larger application...I'm afraid I cannot reduce this more without showing an incomplete thing...

Comment: I had a similar issue with my code and the it looked like `test_client()` was doing something completly unexpected - it could not provide a valid response for any endpoint. All worked on a server. At the end of the day (literally) I noticed the problem was that db initialisation was missing from a one specific test. Not sure that helped your case, but looking back I understand the main difference between 'working' server code and 'failing' local code is the database. )